# How to solve this definite integral?

Tags: integration

$$\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\left(\frac{x^3+\cos \left(x\right)+1}{1+\cos \left(x\right)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Any calculation program can't do it.

Comment: $2\pi$ or undefined depend on how you interpret the integral.

Answer (score 4):

To provide an explanation of achille's comment below your question, split the integral into

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{x^3}{1+\cos(x)}\,dx+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\,dx$$

Now $1+\cos(x)$ is $0$ $x=\pm \pi$ which creates some problems. This leads to the integral being "undefined" as achille states. Still if we interpret it to mean $$\lim_{t\to\pi}\int_{-t}^{t}f(x)\,dx$$

Then we can proceed as follows.

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{x^3}{1+\cos(x)}\,dx+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}1\,dx$$

The first term is $0$ since it is the integral of an odd function. The second term is $\pi - (-\pi)=2\pi$